# Where do I report a bug about Neo4j server

Tags: neo4j

I ran the following Cypher query against Neo4j 2.0

Match n:Resource where  n.Id = '5' SET n :snap delete n;

It repeatably crashes the server!!

Yes I know - the query doesnt make sense. The 'delete n' bit was a copy paste error, and should not have been included.

The point is it crashed the server. Which is not good!!

Comment: Good question. But... I don't believe this fits the StackOverflow guidelines, since it's not really a programming question, but rather a Neo4j support question related to a bug (and a bug in a version under development, still in beta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is the place for issues: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues